# Earth model loses color on import

Tags: import, color

I am trying to import an Earth Model that I downloaded. When I load it into my project it loses all of its color and is only grey. When I load the model as its own project it works just fine.

Does anyone have any idea why I lose color on the model when moving it from one project to another?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "Alpha" input is in the "Base color" of the principled node:

### [image]

- 

Then it will look like this:

### [image]

- 
- 
- 

If you put the "Color" input in the "Base Color" output on the principled node:
[image]

Then it will have color:
[image]

-

-
Hope this helps!